# DOMPDF garbling output

Tags: php, dompdf

At the end of January, I wrote a script to produce PDF files from HTML using the DOMPDF library.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>test</title>

        <style type="text/css">

            *{
                color:#715335;
                font-family:Helvetica, Arial, Serif;
            }

            .i{font-style: italic;}
            .b{font-weight:bold;}

            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{display:inline;}
            h1{font-size:350%;}
            h3{font-size:275%;}
            h6{font-size:150%;}
            span{font-size:125%;}
            div{background-color:#fedebd;}

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div align="center" style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;padding:0px;">
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <img src="img/banner/Bronze/top.gif" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <h1 class="b" style="color:#715335;">Bronze Certificate</h1>
            <br />
            <br />
            <h3 class="i" style="color:#715335;">Ruth Candlish</h3>
            <br />
            <br />
            <h6 style="color:#715335;">This certificate has been awarded to you for earning over 250 points on the LEAP System.</h6>
            <br />
            <br />
            <img src="img/barry.gif" />
            <br /><br />
            <img src="img/badge.gif" />
            <br />
            <h6 class="i">Date Awarded: 14-03-2013</h6>
            <br />
            <br />
            <span>Awarded by: Middle School</span>
            <br />
            <br />
            <img src="img/banner/Bronze/bottom.gif" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using two segments of code to save and render the PDF file. One is just a simple `compile` function which generates the HTML according to input variables (i.e. student name, number of points, etc) and the other is this:

```
/*
 * @param   string  $data           : <HTML> from $this->compile();
 * @param   string  $size           : "a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6"...
 * @param   string  $orientation    : "landscape", "portrait"
 * @param   string  $name           : The name of the student, used to prefix the name of the output file
 */
public function save($data, $size, $orientation, $name, $type){
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->set_paper($size, $orientation);
    $dompdf->load_html($data);
    $dompdf->render();
    $data = $dompdf->output();

    $filename = 'data/'.$type.'/'.$name.' - '.date("d-m-Y").'.pdf';
    return file_put_contents($filename, $data);
}
```

At the time, this script ran perfectly. The PDF was created and saved, with images.

I've come back to it today, to find two things:

1. Images aren't working in saved PDFs, though there is no X to indicate that they're missing
2. There's a huge amount of garbled text output which I suspect may be an image in character form

Here's some of the output:

```
‰PNG


IHDR»<  û;8úPLTEÿÿÿÅ__ÀVVÉlií%š$î:+ÃaUª4&ïK6ïD2ðW>ðQ9ñaEñ\BórU½VAònQòjMñeIòˆlôƒeô‚eô€bó}_ô`óz\ô|\óxZôyYóvXôwWö–yö’tõqõoõ‹mõˆjõ†hõ…fô‚cô~^ô|[¥:ù°—ø¥Š÷Ÿƒö›~öoökø‹iõ‰gÃdDúº¢ø«ö—uÎ|\±L&úÃ¬Æo<º`*Ø–hÞ¥uÕ‘EÍ„,Åxâ¯jç¾€ß¨SÙ /îÎ‡æºUä¶3íÍfôÝÛ­øæ˜þçƒþëŒþë†óÞzÿê{üålå¿ûî›ôç•ÿî‘ùèŠþî‰þëÿì~þìzþëwõápÿësóÞXÿèYÿæSî×LìÓ2ùÙîÍûØýÛûô»úñ­úï£îã–úí”ÿò•ùìùìùìŠøëˆøë…øë„øë‚øê€øê}ÜÏnøéz÷éxøétøéoøèjþëm÷çfþêg÷æ\þë_ÿçIûåCùä<þä5þã,ïÕ#ÿâ#þâÿáíÓõ×
øÝ
ÿáüÜ    ýÝûÛÿÞüÝÿÞõêŽùí‡ÿô÷ça÷çU÷åLöã+ñÛþèøâôÞÿåþöŒÿôuÿòHþì&õãöâÿîþôVýñÿúkþø8ÿþ¡ÿÿŒÿþxÿþYÿþFÿý-ÿþÿýØé½Ðå¯Ëâ§ÆàŸÂÞ˜¿Ü”¼ÚŽ¹Ù‰±Õ|­Óu¨ÑlžÍY˜ÊN¶Ø…´×£ÏcÆ<zÀÄ/…Æ;‰ÉU’ÍPÍGËiœÒg›Òb˜Ð]–ÐZ”Îu¢Ör ÕnŸÔkÓe™Ña–Ï“´Þ‹¯Ü…¬Û€©Ù}¦Øy¤×ržÓoœÓl™Ð²Èç¤¿ã™¸à—9‘(ˆ$~"¸@Zœ.³3L¯'B¥7¾QeŸ+«'6Ä`eŸ!'™"•¿QU½LP»EJ¯48ª.2¦*-£%*›$ÂXZ·AC³<=M$æ‚tRNS@æØf,IDAThÍÚwXTwºð±D(d2E)S£ˆn¢‘&EÁÜ«fe]MŒ’½H‡À‚ÛM\“Ñ{APÈf€Xh*  }Á¬fM@©áyîïô33ewó¸÷ý#É3çŒóÉ÷yÏ¯iß~îÜßÎž9súô©'âããbcböí=~ìÈîOwîð÷óòòÚ¾yËÎ]»;¾o_Ll\|ü‰§NŸ>sæì¹sç¾ßÿ%ím•5‡Ëe±Õ?û>á»ïÎ; Øw}¶cûv/¯CÛwìüt÷‘cÇ÷î‹‰‰%ègÏ~—ð··$ç2ù¦|Ó¥|º5ùÓý¸ýlÇsÿ|'fßòÙ.Ø¾²ÇŸ8u
ØÏ¼M;‡Éä±--,,yæ|æÌì[6ÿÿ°[šs¹–¶6k–/_naÊgLgÏËåÀ.eeíº •H$Ivüç…¬Ý<.“¥ÅÄŠÅ'Ôìß¾
; ³@ê¶+l–¯¶15§SÚÓO¸¯³÷ï“müè#O©§ÀÁQ°á?7§nu¹ot»˜–æážþÖí‡Áe[[ü
›Õ¶|sJ{¶ÊÙ]å$sëú=·
&'›\{¤®]_ˆ<ÃNrùG“ÙoÝÎg›,aÒ9,+K8z¶9>Ú¨Ûû=ävn²þuYY‹Æ¤Á|_‰ëÈ&©ëàEnóåòu‹ÞºÅ ,1Å¢_ckÊ£´'÷Û½t–ywoe¹õ…»D²adÖœÁ9Q¢9“º¼ÿv6ÇLßÈÐÀl1Ž~…-Zµr_'ëwÊÊHa»ëð†ó.ƒGDƒAÏF1°g§ÿîöFe]²iš‹,®¡ž1À/1aÒÙ,+.>Ljô»{\·½l]·§[·ƒT2Øá~¹tyî¯ëuw>™þûÚÔ)êë”õ•
j=›m¨£¿è—˜ñy¶•—2÷ôd{;;ç´L™ÓÔ¤›t§ÔÁôŒàÏÒ
"™ÌM öX´hÊã÷µ×(šÛZž>m©­TP]·þÐlÞ= G£gó(í'NˆãÓäiÐø.ÊsÓ!   ˜›àñýˆH¶w_š<Vœý{÷L›BÙô¨µµåé“'
•Í7XðYºîzÉ¥¶k¬  û!|^ÑžWÿu»¢NYÛø ½
Ò7V·QÜa²Òp®®½   ÛÜrFö7® þe;ˆ½JQWÛØð¨­õéCeðækõæÎCð¸\>~åßl¯©©º_¥¨W6AÑ?l¬¤ºÇ”g©?wî<]Æt61­ÒöïOÈÍÍÍ
ô²¬gd2´ž‘J¡õ(ðY"øT.—Cýž
Ý›UÊþ™ÚƒÏS_hTÞ¯¨®F£oy@ù´ÒÌµL=]]ý%,¶)‡dÏøj=ZÎH9!åÊ+777øsøäÛ2ffŠAm//¿¿ºªŠþQ#µÆá¸’Íá¬b3äÿ’»íWP TPuCÕß××70ÐÛÛÛÓÓÓÕÕõìÙàà3ðïžžÞ^p¥»Üîÿõ“Ü¿Ì„.Œõ;xÐ+ü°¿öµšŽò²òŠûpô5j¦±ƒQžÇeré<µ¿Ìøj¨shhèÅ‹ßž?Ÿ˜xùr|||llljjrrttddxö«Y³ç€šõjxdtrrjl|üåÄÄóß^uÎÌ.û{<àëx4PëbûÏUeŽÌP3øóˆú:ãÛwþYû¶™Øý"ÃÃC‚ÀÖ÷À°(íËŠÇåeeHôÕJEû?d?™’²ŒÒ>ì£ýÕ4vÕÐW¹_¿ùB#G   ÃÎ¼…½¡¹ Â—•—W(š(‡™éË'%×îWÌþ³Oõ
ŒŽööŽ¾îéÉgöÎw¾Ï8ùæ‰J:Gª}½þçŽ
_Qÿ¸ŠúO°bsè\:.:›´ÛöNÈ]ÛßÁÃöEž.}}Ž›æ÷
opîqøÂaµMŽaöe)d{~IqI±ö/N<)ð£ ÕÕt(+«?+ë(åÖï3ø¦|&T|¦©ùÒxø(ùW’½ßþÝçˆ½oQÖ Uâ:ÇQ"qtØšåð³¯›@íö¹   „ýfaÁ­7ò
ó5;ðhòÅ¤h½0ø¼0˜’§¬yüø±òå5“ÉcY‚íÞ
¸,8æ¦Llç”û  fïv¶ëÇì¢+RéŽÍ_ÉöÍRéç¸}jÊy³¯ÏM ~ÐoÞ¸þÓ¢[š¹““/^LÑG†Sñ¯-&ƒÁ²µ±Y³:%X
êãÕ6<óPü—_Cƒ$dW¹ÛwöOwnÙ.ñ’Ú¼c'aï]ä1€ô4Döü’’‚| ÿ)¯DóçC¯%Ç‚è££„Â”¾”A·²]a‹ÄŽþ|ü±¥ùR|ùRJÆ²Î¨ÝYE¶ï8ôÀB’l_çƒÚUCÿ›q    ÿ‘‚¢"€Ïm£e
Jºz59>6qºØÛ444´7h]á3¹`£daâm`<Ð[˜›[A×} †Çìîª—ãã¨=õÐpïè&éÄ>Û}ú{ç²\Ò£š»´¨Ž¾@«ã…þ i¢Â)SoR**ŠJ¸=Ï6ç²¬¬,¡³HoCDomn
ßïî‰‰ñ±q0Î öY=¯ûlÈîŽÚŸCíîCØKïÜ¾]TXœŸG1Ôøú‡PÈkšuíÚÚÚZ[[Û•jc
ŸÎa¿g
ôšÑ¯^Í[
ÿMÆ5Ððˆ=¹Ó>m\åí¦šBsïÃrïqHêê‰uúÅµ¿PmËÝOüLþí{wJoCÑkõÌkª¹¹®¡­åáÃ§`×ôäÉßÿþôAU}-~Õò—Ãf³¬µ£ÿØv)¼*ƒg§°Ý9ÛÝCîá$KrÚbowutõƒúýŠ§ËÙF7yœ“Ø±«–edfÕ›ÅwïÝ½SZZT’7sºRQÛÞ
Uì
ô­•ÄÜÊaðt gY[kD¿fõÆð=pÓ v±8N.ƒ6¬ˆ,ßáqf·Ht|¯ìWÅÙ¨´LŠÉ‘_Pz÷îÛ%±…
¡E°0Tctoª¬ihoo‡úÂ#úbÇÍ¤3Mïs9µèW }c½ž`¿É¸üN'j—;'eîE^@§íÛ!;Ø8eÎÈãâQ{¿ê+òè*/¯zXµäÂÈˆðÐàPad¤Ú¼
vÙ`€Úý£ªFÌÎ51[Ì¤Ž~¹%r´šŒ4¸}Ê[†¼øØrÚ7mÆì]³   {§]nÊ%
å­›ÚýÀÀØ×÷@àaÒXÓ¨¨­­ônüf,x.}‰™‰Éb=¦_nn rÿ{HEaOõstpü“d‹¶ý9˜˜R´»C«¢Â¼BuáŒ"–’Êºæfe­VôOUµcv33ýûPôxã@ø5|Ä~)%Ç¾ó7¼g^îÉ„íRçƒÓì¤Z=óRõnnÆ7jÊ¼‚âââ’’bõ¦‰
õó‚^ZáúDòJø<‹þŒú'-•hÓpè†Kàè™<:=‹4àX.F—d)9—:‡P{\Zú²LêÐ–ï=Ô¾73-Ë]õ‰ú“ZPR’ŸêV^IañqxD€€?ŠGô^‰^èÅææ*E=¤oj"Gÿôa½³@z´ëÙøLìhîPðë;1{nôƒ  iNê…O5ì*»œŒÿQ£ç…Øõë?ºQH5¡AAï‡ã}}…èÊ ¥¾ìóHÑ·#Ñ?li®ÅìFF††@FÏe]¿Â
³ÓR~¼:¤š@í1ÓØáw”}â—m9äØóón‚ºqãÌÇÇIÿÈ°ÐOŠÞ×íø¶fEuÀÃú¦Æâ™%Ùa=½)“žYö{¨~…³ŸLÉqÿõùLí¿¬ÏI¹FŠ½ôË­[°¿o‚…Âp ?Fë}F"[›`ƒ]G_§Ä£oki%ìÆ5¢ÇºÞÖ·ÓR.çØuÂs“Xž–)ƒS/`v©ôÂ‘H–™™–ÏMÝ/ü1ƒDÏÃ:ªG¢¿Uˆ\#z„îÁ¤èŒôGí•`
ð•h×#Ïlka_¨oðXô ëyØ"Á‚ÅÀí>)9é/:Ó}|â¼½½÷ìIüâ‹­ç=°ýÏ¡‘‡FïÙs16Î¬    Ž!íÅ%‹þ§ë¨=("
Â‡…]À+Ò±++¡£
XOŽ¾­­·ëë-\hL=À“ì´«g³Ý;ûŸ÷CGÈ)rÆb[í±_œsÎ’Ôü‚ÂÂ’bRô×¯cöÃQ‘Xô˜Þ+Í]YUã‘g¶© êúöf’]_àµ£·b“ì´«§³;ûAML øô|†°÷ôº}ÎirÇ€‘½°Â“¢/(@í‰‡!==hœƒ~XîUåÑ7v½žˆž.YÉN»œžm¯zãÙRßTvz†º½¨àa==Éx‹>íz,÷Ÿ«Ë*Èx4ú0;›¾@GO‰ÞoSÐ8¯n?   ðvª×ÛG=û²ú©L^Øu’£GíIþ0ÚõÈ€C¶—#ÉãÑ××Ac=Öïì÷è,X §½    =WÍNó¹,Û©^géLÎ>­±v°ëP‹³G^„ð zâ™õ@ímÀæÑ£3Un§ëèÂxu=òÌréjvšOºXÚflûì‘ÞQqö©du:-/¿´ô¶zô„:@¢G»> ëwØN½²®ùƒy::Ñ›™ðùtõÜi´ät±ÜYÕ7]î½‰ÅéštÈ~ÒÑç£ö€ÈXŸHDŒæNCìd=}3jg®Ò›§««C=i­áðNO“»wwÃG©šö®'¹8Ý‡¦Y·òï;=4\â¹ÇAxrôà™ÅíUe$<1\Ö×¡/Z¹«ŒæêBxµè®ç˜hAââceÞSÝãZöÁ®áòØto­o€ÜïÜEõDôhîqÒ“¢ÇÁÊº²²2Šèë›Ñƒ+k‰^½qù\ž¶„#“9u÷iØ»™ò˜x
:j'G_ŒÎMáqÉqÑG„‡£ßkz\¡ŽG¢¯Vâ/û–®5žëu°ÆAñF†lSà3Ež‹ú;t†í)ËŒ‰¥ºàKïÝÅõpôØMPôÕx<úh4zü[ÙTV¦ýýJ%~Êaa¾VàçiDodlÌã0µpýußqQ–Ë¢¾ÞÑ°ž™5k¸kŽXŠíÛC};íV!°£z8úló’|$DõG…‘ø÷jWiá+ª›Hïœ>\9ÇãÑë/\ÌZj;
†–ðR—Ù½½£³‡G,#GOw3t(FàKo—’6aaW¯%“¢OŠ"¿>P´W—©éËËï75“ÿJ„Á*K¹êÑë-Ðg®2Õ Õêð‘R©«`´wDàš*½räØkî¥åü½{ˆþÎ"ÒžÕ/<,ùÚÕääd”¦vžªh¨/WÓWwh¼Aà¸Ö@wî\Ø<·z†œUÄ_) ®]Ÿ¥J$›7H¤>ßµõõ÷æçÝ½‡d_Z¤vF&£èxÔž”®þEåãŽªŠr¬î×uÔ5ªß@c0W®43ÖC†xý…FK¸,®ÖÐ®]Á;R¡s±Ô-o¼ô<Ødƒá:]Ò8¤    öãz8øGhXæ÷¾ã1R5Jí?ÙŠÇüƒ¥åJ¤¬­þÀÓœP§©ÿòò:ô§ÝI£ÝÌƒ
(®üðC¨à (¿×Þ„õ[í=°êå¢ïÊ8VøÇÿ ©/&ÿIEND®B`‚
```

I find it odd that "PNG" is labelled towards the top of the output too - none of the files being used are PNG files, though they may have been converted from such in Photoshop at one time or other.

If I remove the image files from their directory, the garbled output disappears - presumably because DOMPDF isn't rendering them. The PDFs are still created, but this time the images exist as little "X" marks to indicate they're missing.

If I `echo` before `$dompdf->render()` and `echo` after, the `echo`'d content appears before and after the garbled output - so (again, presumably) that's the problem function.

The only thing that I believe to have changed since Jan 30th is that our network manager upgraded PHP from version 5.2.9 to 5.3.

We're using IIS to host this webserver.

I've tried to Google the problems but nobody appears to be having the same issue. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You are echoing the source of your png image. If you right click on any png image, and open with a text editor.. You will see similar output

Comment: That's what I thought @DarylGill. Problem is - I'm not using PNG files, nor am I echo'ing that kind of content. The script hasn't changed since January 30th of this year.

Comment: I've added a line to my OP about `dompdf->render()` which might explain things further.

Comment: dompdf converts GIF images to PNG for placement in the PDF, so that is where the PNG image content is coming from.

Comment: Which version of dompdf? Do you have a link you can share? Would something have changed about your output buffering (OB)? dompdf uses OB to capture the content of a PNG during rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to the latest version of DOMPDF and now I have a totally different problem.